# Need help on loading up a clash of clans progress

Tags: clash-of-clans

Ok I started up a clash of clans on my iPad and have it pretty far. Then I got my new phone and I was signed into Game Center but since I wasn't signed in on Game Center on my iPad i can't figure out how to save that progress to put it on my phone. Need help!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain if thisll work, but if you go on support, there is a link account button which gives you a code, but that may just be apple to android.